# How to disable click event in native web compontent?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, web-component, custom-element

Do you have any idea how to disable click event in native web compontent? I've tried to remove event listener in connectedCallback() section but it doesn't work.

How it looks my code:

```
if(state ==='disabled') {
  this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.primary_button").style.backgroundColor = "#D9D9D9";
  this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.primary_button").style.color = "#333333";
  this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.primary_button").style.cursor = "not-allowed";

  this.removeEventListener('click',  e => {
    this.dispatchCustomEvent();
  });
}
```

Comment: Very vague question. There are multiple ways, but you need to be specific. Maybe post your code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code as well.

Comment: `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();` should do the trick

Comment: I edited my first post

Comment: can you add the html code? and the entire code of the js? or atleast the function

Comment: I added code snipet below

Answer (score 0):

```js
class ingButton extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
      super();
    }
  
    connectedCallback() {
        this.initShadowDom();

 
        //   this.style.backgroundColor="red";

        var state = this.getAttribute('disabled');

        if(state ==='disabled')
        {

         this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.primary_button").style.backgroundColor = "#D9D9D9";
         this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.primary_button").style.color = "#333333";
         this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.primary_button").style.cursor = "not-allowed";


         this.removeEventListener('click',  e => {
             this.dispatchCustomEvent();
          });

        }

        // this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click',  e => {
        //     this.dispatchCustomEvent();
        //   });
    }
    get divs() {
        return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
    }

    dispatchCustomEvent(){
        var event = new CustomEvent('build', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: false,
          });  
        this.dispatchEvent(event)
        // this.style.display = "inline-block"
        // this.shadowRoot.dispatchEvent(event)
    }

    get Template() {
      return `
       <style>
        .primary_button
        {
            border-width: 0px;
            border-radius:4px;
            width: 140px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: #FF6200;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: normal;
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            disabled: disabled;
        }

        .text_button
        {
            border-width: 0px;
            border-radius:4px;
            border: none;
            width: 140px;
            height: 40px;
            background: inherit;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            disabled: disabled;
        }

        .text
        {
            border-width: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 136px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            font-family: 'ING Me';
            font-weight: 410;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 13px;
            disabled: disabled;
        }
       </style>

        <div class="primary_button">
        <div class="text_button">
        <div class="text">
        <p><span>Generate report</span></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      `;
    }

      initShadowDom() {
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = this.Template;

        
      }

      attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        // When the drawer is disabled, update keyboard/screen reader behavior.
        if (this.disabled) {
            console.log("disabled");
          this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
        }
        // TODO: also react to the open attribute changing.
      }
  }
  window.customElements.define('ing-button', ingButton);
```

```html
     <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="ing-button.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 200px;">
        <ing-button onclick="invokeAlert()" disabled="disabled" ></ing-button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function invokeAlert()
    {
        alert("test");
    }
</script>
```

JavaScript:

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is a fix:

It is not that you want to try to remove any event listener, instead you want to get there before the user defined event listener and prevent it from happening.

To do this you need to have an event listener on the `shadowRoot`. That `click` event will happen before the element `click` event. Then, if your component is disabled, you must call `evt.preventDefault();` and `evt.stopImmediatePropagation();` to prevent the `onclick` from happening.

In the example below I removed things that were not needed for the example and I added a few things that I will describe below.

```js
class ingButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = this.Template;

    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      if (this.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
        this.dispatchCustomEvent();
      }
    },true);
  }
  
  dispatchCustomEvent(){
    var event = new CustomEvent('build', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: false,
    });  
    this.dispatchEvent(event)
  }
  
  get disabled() {
    return this.hasAttribute('disabled');
  }
  set disabled(val) {
    if (val) {
      this.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    }
    else {
      this.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  }

  get divs() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
  }

  get Template() {
    return `
     <style>
      :host([disabled]) .primary_button {
        background-color: #D9D9D9;
        color: #333;
        cursor: not-allowed;
      }

      .primary_button
      {
        border-width: 0px;
        border-radius:4px;
        width: 140px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #FF6200;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: normal;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .text_button
      {
        border-width: 0px;
        border-radius:4px;
        border: none;
        width: 140px;
        height: 40px;
        background: inherit;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
      }

      .text
      {
        border-width: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 136px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        font-family: 'ING Me';
        font-weight: 410;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 13px;
      }
     </style>

      <div class="primary_button">
      <div class="text_button">
      <div class="text">
      <p><span>Generate report</span></p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('ing-button', ingButton);

customElements.whenDefined('ing-button').then(() => {
  let ingButton = document.querySelector('ing-button');
  
  ingButton.addEventListener('build', evt => {
    alert('ing-button: build event');
  });

  document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', evt => {
    ingButton.disabled = !ingButton.disabled;
  });
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
<ing-button onclick="alert('clicked on')" disabled></ing-button>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

I added the toggle button to allow me to enable and disable the custom element.
I added a `disabled` property for easy ability to set the state.
I moved the creation of shadowDOM and the internal `click` handler into the constructor. Notice the `true` at the end of the `addEventListener` call. That uses `capture` mode. ([Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) for more info on `capture` mode vs. `bubble` mode for events.)
There is no need to worry about the disabled attribute using attributeChangedCallback since we check the existence of the `disabled` attribute every time the user clicks on our component.
I added CSS to auto set the color and cursor when disabled:

```
  :host([disabled]) .primary_button {
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    color: #333;
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
```

Any other questions, just ask.

**UPDATE 1**

I will add that if you are trying to act like a button that your code should probably use a `<button>` instead of trying to make your own. There are many things that exist in a button that are difficult/time consuming to add. And if you want your site to work well with the visually impaired then you should really use the `<button>` instead of making your own.